# JavaScript empty string slice

Tags: javascript

I was using a for loop to conditionally iterate over HTML input and concatenate a pipe separated string. Because I didn't want an ending pipe character I used `foo.slice(0, -1)`.

It occurred to me that it is possible that there is no input and so `foo` would be an empty string. I was not sure if `foo.slice(0, -1)` is cross browser safe in this case so I tried this:

```
var foo = "";
foo = foo.slice(0, -1);
```

Firefox's "Browser Console" did not complain surprisingly so I assume some kind of bounds checking is going on but wanted to ask to be sure. I know that a test like `if (foo) …` would be enough to check for an empty string but was unsure if it is necessary. I couldn't seem to find anything about this in references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [ECMA 5.1 Specifications for `Array.prototype.slice`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.10), if the end is is negative, then the maximum of length + end index and zero will be used.

> If `relativeEnd` is negative, let final be `max((len + relativeEnd),0);` else let final be `min(relativeEnd,len)`.

So, it will safely use `0` for ending, even if the string is empty and if you pass negative index.